# Keep getting same answer in loop but think its due to my return

Tags: java, methods, for-loop

I've update my code, however it continues to put the number that I initialize years to at the bottom of the table that prints out when ran.  And I'm still trying to figure out how to use the %.2d in the print out section to create 2 place decimals.  so any feedback on that too would be helpful.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Investment {

public static double futureInvestmentValue(double investmentAmount, double monthlyInterestRate, int years){

double futureInvestmentValue = 0.0;

for (years = 1; years <=30; years++){
    //calculate futureInvestmentValue
    futureInvestmentValue += (investmentAmount * (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, years * 12)));
    System.out.print(years + "\t" + futureInvestmentValue + "\n");

}//end for
return futureInvestmentValue;
}//end futureInvestmentValue

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //obtain Investment amount
    System.out.print("Enter Investment amount: ");
    double investmentAmount = input.nextDouble();

    //obtain monthly interest rate in percentage
    System.out.print("Enter annual interest rate in percentage: ");
    double annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();

    //calculate annual interest rate
    double monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate / 1200);

int years = 1;

System.out.println("Years\t" + "Future Value");

System.out.print(years + "\t" + futureInvestmentValue(investmentAmount, monthlyInterestRate, years) + "\n");

}//end main
}//
```

Comment: It seems that you are multiplying by 100 and then dividing by 100 which is just redundant.

Comment: The best approach to both code design and fixing your problem would be to break out the calculation into a separate method and run unit tests on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning the same value you are getting from the Scanner:

double investmentAmount = input.nextDouble();

You should return futureInvestmentValue.

And, as pointed in other comment, you are looping but you aren't changing but once the value of the variables in the loop, so you can avoid the loop or check the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You never modify any of the terms used in calculating this `annualInterest`

`double annualInterest = (1-1 / Math.pow(investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate), years * 12));`